# Jhipster Extends Microservice Solution

Tags: java, architecture, microservices, jhipster

I use jhipster in a new project that needs different customizations for each client. 
Every microservice (registry office, accounting etc ...) must be able to be customized according to some customer needs. 
Which is the best solution to manage an extendable microservice with different customizations for each client?

Tnk!!

Answer (score 0):

In my point of view, you should ask yourself: Why do you want to have such a shared microservice stub that all the other service have to use as a basis. There are good reasons I am aware of but one big strength of a microservice architecture is that each service can make use of the technology which is best suited for its business needs.

Getting back to your question, you could create a Git repository with a basic JHipster setup which only contains those application parts that all microservices should have in common. Then you can create forks of this repository for each microservice.

Another approach: Instead of having a single base project you could create small modules of those features that all microservices should have in common, e.g. a common logging mechanism. Then all microservice projects can use these modules as dependencies.

Comment: Hello,
what I mean is that every service needs some customizations
for each customer. For example, the billing microservice needs
that for a customer, when he saves the bill, write more tables than
to another customer for whom these tables should not be written.

Comment: You should implement your core business logic as a module which provides hooks for extensions. For example, implement a billing module which allows to plug in extensions for interesting events. Then use that common module in multiple customer projects and extend the logic as needed.